# Recyclerview lags while scrolling up and down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my Android application I am using a Recyclerview to scroll items. It lags while scrolling the page. I have found more solutions for that problem but still it doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```java
 listAdapter = new FeedRecycleAdapter_Sample(this, feedItems);
 listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
 listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

And where I put above code to call adapter class.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Following is adapter class which I am using to call from MainActivity class.

**FeedRecycleAdapter_Sample.java**

```
public class FeedRecycleAdapter_Sample extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public FeedRecycleAdapter_Sample(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolderImage mViewHolder = new ViewHolderImage(mView);
    return mViewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder v, final int position) {
    final ViewHolderImage viewHolderImage = (ViewHolderImage) v;
    final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
    getImageIDValue = item.getImage_id();
    getVideoIDValue = item.getVideo_id();
    getAudioIDValue = item.getAudio_id();
    getDocIDValue = item.getDoc_id();

    if (!(item.getImge()).equals("") || !(item.getVideo()).equals("") || !(item.getAudio()).equals("") || !(item.getFile()).equals("")) {
        if (!getImageIDValue.equals("0") || !getVideoIDValue.equals("0") || !getAudioIDValue.equals("0") || !getDocIDValue.equals("0")) {
            if (!getImageIDValue.equals("0")) {
                getValue_data = "0";
            }
            if (!getVideoIDValue.equals("0")) {
                getValue_data = "1";
            }
            if (!getAudioIDValue.equals("0")) {
                getValue_data = "2";
            }
            if (!getDocIDValue.equals("0")) {
                getValue_data = "3";
            }
            switch (getValue_data) {
                case "0":

                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView
                            .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                }
                            });
                    break;

                case "1":

                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setImageUrl(ConfigUrl.Vdo_PNG, imageLoader);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView
                            .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                }
                            });
                    break;
                case "2":
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setImageUrl(ConfigUrl.Audio_PNG, imageLoader);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView
                            .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                }
                            });
                    break;

                case "3":
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setImageUrl(ConfigUrl.Doc_PNG, imageLoader);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolderImage.feedImageView
                            .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                }
                            });
                    break;
            }
        }

    } else {
        viewHolderImage.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    viewHolderImage.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, ActComment.class);
            i.putExtra("postId", item.getId());
            i.putExtra("uid", item.getUser_id());
            GET_POST_M = item.getId();
            activity.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    viewHolderImage.name.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolderImage.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String cd=item.getName();
            String c =cd.substring(cd.lastIndexOf(" "));
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", c.trim(), null));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            activity.startActivity(callIntent);
         }
     });

    if(!item.getMemID().equals("")){
        viewHolderImage.d_number.setText(item.getMemID());
    }
    else{
        viewHolderImage.d_number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();
    Long d=Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp())* 1000;
    viewHolderImage.timestamp.setText(prettyTime.format(new Date(d)));


    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
        viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String checkText= viewHolderImage.statusMsg.getText().toString().trim();
        boolean isContain = containsURL(checkText);
        boolean isEmail=containsEmail(checkText);
        boolean isPhone=containsPhone(checkText);

        if(isContain==true){
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        if(isEmail==true){
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        if(isPhone==true){
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }

    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        viewHolderImage.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    if(!(item.getAudioURL()).equals("")){
        viewHolderImage.docNameUrl1.setText(item.getAudioURL());
        viewHolderImage.docNameUrl1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        viewHolderImage.docNameUrl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(!(item.getFileURL()).equals("")){
        viewHolderImage.docNameUrl.setText(item.getFileURL());
        viewHolderImage.docNameUrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        viewHolderImage.docNameUrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
   // viewHolderImage.profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);
    if(item.getProfilePic()!=null) {
        if(!item.getProfilePic().equals("default.png")) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(item.getProfilePic());
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            final Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2, true);
            viewHolderImage.profilePic.setImageBitmap(bm);

            viewHolderImage.profilePic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new PhotoFullPopupWindow(activity,bm);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            viewHolderImage.profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
        }
    }
    else{
        viewHolderImage.profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
    }




    //click listener
    viewHolderImage.docNameUrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(activity, Single_file.class);
            i.putExtra("single_file", item.getFile());
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.finish();
        }
    });
    viewHolderImage.docNameUrl1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(activity, StreamingMp3Player.class);
            i.putExtra("single_audio", item.getAudio());
            activity.startActivity(i);

            activity.finish();
        }
    });




    //like post
    viewHolderImage.like_liked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (viewHolderImage.like_liked1.getDrawable()== activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.liked)) {


                viewHolderImage.like_liked1.setImageResource(R.drawable.likes);
            }else{
                viewHolderImage.like_liked1.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked);
                like_post(MainActivity_Sample.GET_UID,item.getId());
            }

        }
    });


    //comment_count

    if(!(item.getComment_count()).equals("0")){
        if((item.getComment_count()).equals("1")){
            viewHolderImage.ccount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolderImage.ccount.setText(item.getComment_count()+" comment");

        }
        else {
            viewHolderImage.ccount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolderImage.ccount.setText(item.getComment_count() + " comments");

        }
    }
    else {
        viewHolderImage.ccount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    //like & comment count layout
    if(viewHolderImage.getlike.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE && viewHolderImage.ccount.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
        viewHolderImage.like_comment_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //comment click event
    if(viewHolderImage.ccount.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        viewHolderImage.ccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent(activity, ActComment.class);
                //Toast.makeText(activity, "success!"+item.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                i.putExtra("postId", item.getId());
                i.putExtra("uid", item.getUser_id());


                GET_POST_M=item.getId();
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolderImage extends ViewHolder {

    TextView name,timestamp,statusMsg,url, docNameUrl,docNameUrl1,ccount, getlike, d_number;
    CircleImageView profilePic;
    ImageView delete,like_liked1;
    FeedImageView feedImageView,feedImageViewV,feedImageViewA,feedImageViewD;
    LinearLayout comment,like_comment_count,like_liked;
    public ViewHolderImage( View convertView) {
        super(convertView);
        name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        d_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.d_number);
        delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        getlike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getlike);
        like_liked1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_liked1);
        like_liked=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_liked);
        docNameUrl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDocUrl);
        docNameUrl1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDocUrl1);
        timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        ccount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ccount);
        profilePic = (CircleImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
        textview=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
        like_comment_count=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_comment_count);
        comment=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you share your adapter code with us for review your code?

Comment: Any images on the items?

Comment: The shared code is irrelevant to the problem may you show the FeedRecycleAdapter_Sample and its ViewHolder.

Comment: What is the .setImageUrl implementation or is it a library? Just want to make sure you are downloading the image in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I found a solution for that problem. I'm using the following code to convert url into bitmap. This will take more time to convert from url into bitmap. So I'm using Glide to set image url instead of converting into bitmap.`url = new URL(item.getProfilePic());
 image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            final Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2, true);
            viewHolderImage.profilePic.setImageBitmap(bm);`